# how to change bar hover color of highchart dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I set bar hover color using below code:

```
plotOptions: {column: {states: {hover: {color: '#000000'}}}}
```

But how can I change the bar hover color dynamically?

Comment: Dynamically means? You need to set colors from a group of colors?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `point.update(options)`, where in options you will set new hover color:

```
    chart.series[0].data[0].update({
        states: {
            hover: {
                color: "red"
            }    
        }
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xoje27rt/

Answer (score 1):

Defined set of colors, when you load charts every time you will experience a different color of hover effect from the given set

```
var colors= ['#7cb5ec', '#434348', '#90ed7d', '#f7a35c', '#8085e9', 
   '#f15c80', '#e4d354', '#2b908f', '#f45b5b', '#91e8e1'];


    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) );

            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            color: colors[x]                                                           
                        }
                    }

                }
            },
```

And a [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/6y4tb8jh/) for details

For future continual work, make a button to trigger chart reload

Comment: Nice one! Do you know how to highlight each bar with different color?

Comment: @patL Yes, please raise a separate question and paste the link here! So that it will be helpful for others as well

Comment: I just asked a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52082815/change-bar-colors-dynamically-highcharts). Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

create a chart after some event of a drop down from where you want to get color. something like`<select id="idd" onChange="getColor()">
  <option value="red">R</option>
  <option value="green">G</option>
  </select>`

 I have done a little bit [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3kppzqg7/). will improve it soon.