# change bar colors dynamically - highcharts

Tags: highcharts, hover

I'm a `R` programmer trying to parse some `JS` code though `highcharter` package.

I'm trying to change each bar color on hover with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6y4tb8jh/) example based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365381/how-to-change-bar-hover-color-of-highchart-dynamically/30366231?noredirect=1#comment91115369_30366231) question.

I've tried this:

```
plotOptions: {
  column: {
    events: {
      mouseOver: function () {

        this.chart.series[this.index].update({
          color: 'blue'
        });
      },
      mouseOut: function () {

        this.chart.series[this.index].update({
          color: '#b0b0b0'
        });                           
      }
    };
    states: {
      hover: {

        color: colors[x]                                                           
      }
    }

  }
}
```

However I can only highlight with the 'blue' color. How can I use a different color for a different `column`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see only the blue color on all columns, because you set those events on series.
In order to achieve it, you can create arrays with colors and assign it to general chart object on `chart.events.load`. Then in `series.point.events.mouseOver` and `mouseOut` should be able to change the color by point index. Here is the example code:

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(events = list(
    load = JS("function() {this.customColors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']}")
  )) %>% 
  hc_series(
    list(
      data =  abs(rnorm(3)) + 1,
      type = "column",
      color = '#ddd',
      point = list(
        events = list(
          mouseOver = JS("function() {this.update({color: this.series.chart.customColors[this.index]})}"),
          mouseOut = JS("function() {this.update({color: '#ddd'})}")
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.point.events

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load